# How to differentiate QT WebKit user agent string from mainstream browsers?

Tags: user-agent, qtwebkit

I have a desktop app that uses QT WebKit, and it requires a different logic in my server application than other browsers (I won't go into details). What's the best way to parse the user agent string & determine whether it is QT WebKit or not?